# What is happening under the hood that allows jest to mock a function that is called from outside the test file?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Here is an example on how to mock a function that is being called from outside the test file.

`math.js`

```
export const add      = (a, b) => a + b;
export const subtract = (a, b) => b - a;
export const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
export const divide   = (a, b) => b / a;
```

`app.js`

```
import * as math from './math.js';

export const doAdd      = (a, b) => math.add(a, b);
export const doSubtract = (a, b) => math.subtract(a, b);
export const doMultiply = (a, b) => math.multiply(a, b);
export const doDivide   = (a, b) => math.divide(a, b);
```

`test.js`

```
import * as app from "./app";
import * as math from "./math";

math.add = jest.fn();
math.subtract = jest.fn();

test("calls math.add", () => {
  app.doAdd(1, 2);
  expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
});

test("calls math.subtract", () => {
  app.doSubtract(1, 2);
  expect(math.subtract).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
});
```

What is jest (and I guess other test libraries) doing under the hood that allows it to mock a function that is called outside the test function? As I see it, when the test file imports `app.js` the test file has no control over the `math` object used in that file, but apparently it does.

Feel free to use another example than the one provided. I am looking for a conceptual explanation of how this wizardry works. Please explain how it works in terms of JavaScript features and at least JavaScript-like pseudo-code.

Thank you!

Comment: Jest's not doing *anything* particular here, you're not using jest.mock. The module is an object, and you're replacing some of its props.

Answer (score 6):

Jest utilizes nodejs vm functionality, that allows to control and modify code execution
https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

That is done in jest-runtime package
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/46c9c13811ca20a887e2826c03852f2ccdebda7a/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L531

You can see detailed description in this video describing jest architecture
jest-runtime && node vm
https://youtu.be/3YDiloj8_d0?t=2251

require interception
https://youtu.be/3YDiloj8_d0?t=2461